# Debug DART output not printing

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

Output display user input integer, instead of Even or Odd

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print('Enter your number: ');
  int n = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  var result = n % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd";
  print('Your number is : $result');
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your question mentions "even" and "odd", but there's nothing in your code related to that.  Exactly what problem are you encountering?

Comment: Hello james, i wanted to take integer from user and check whether it's odd or even. Later i want to print even or odd. But on debug console, after putting an integer result is that integer. Do not taking the next print element.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the exact code you tried (that is, you copied and pasted it and did not retype it)?  When you entered your number, did you press the Enter/Return key?

Comment: Yes, this is exact the same code, i just copied. After giving the number, i hit enter button

Comment: @TagMinor Can you add a screenshot where you show us the code together with the interaction of the program you have where we can see this behavior you are talking about?

Comment: @julemand You can check the picture right before the header

Comment: I suggest renaming the title to something like "dart stdin.readLineSync stdout.write not working in vscode"

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that your program is running inside the "Debug Console" in VS Code. The following explanation can be found in the Dart settings in VS Code:

> The Debug Console has more functionality because the process is controlled by the debug adapter, but is unable to accept input from the user via stdin.

You can change this by going into File -> Preferences -> Settings. Here you go into Extensions -> Dart & Flutter. If you scroll down you can find "Dart: Cli Console". You can also just search for "Dart Cli console":
[image]

Instead of "debugConsole" set this to "terminal". Try start your program again and it should now be running inside the "Terminal" tab instead and you should be able to interact with your program and provide data to it though keyboard inputs.

Comment: I did realize that the problem was with debug console, but I didn't know how to fix it until I saw your answer. upvoted.

Comment: Very nice solution. I was also facing the same problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to change the program from running inside debug console to terminal. To do that open your VSCode settings, and search for dart.cliConsole and change it from Debug Console to terminal.

[Check image for setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7UW8.png)

Before that, make sure you have the flutter extension installed, otherwise you won't see the cli console setting. Hope this helps!