# Running dart terminal in vsCode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create a Dart terminal. So I can use the terminal rather than the Debug Console in Visual Studio Code.

I have already added the terminal statement in `launch.json` file to work with the terminal.
Even with the change shown in the picture below, I can not see dart terminal.
[image: screen from vs code]

Comment: Try take a look at this answer I made earlier today where I made some instructions to get this working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69911118/1953515

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu in your screenshot is the menu for creating a new terminal. Running a Dart script in the terminal will not cause it to appear in this "new terminal" menu, it will instead just start running the Dart process inside the active terminal window.

If you add `"console": "terminal"` to the `launch.json` and then run the project with `F5`, it should start running your app inside the terminal automatically. You'll know this is working by the full command line that the Dart extension is running being printed in the terminal as the process is started.