# where to get the user input in vs code? using dart

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, stdin

I am building a dart program to get the user input. when running the program using the run button I get the output in the output window but I cannot type in it. tried using the terminal to run the program and it worked well. so I want to know what is the right way to take the input from the user?

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print("enter your name: ");
  var name = stdin.readLineSync();

  print("hello mrs ${name}");
}
```

Comment: Could you try follow my answer I gave in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69911118/1953515 . It changes console used in VS code when running Dart and allows user input which is a problem for det default choosen console.

Answer (score 3):

From file -> Preferences -> Settings
search for "Dart: Cli Console"
[Dart: Cli Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be9bg.png)

Then change the drop-down menu into -terminal-
now you can run again your code and check
you can type in the terminal and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer regarding using the correct vs-code console is correct but you should also check out the dcli package and it's ask function.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of dcli.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the right way using terminal as you did. It's not a fail. It's just how it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to change the program from running inside debug console to terminal. To do that open your VSCode settings, and search for dart.cliConsole and change it from Debug Console to terminal.

[Check image for setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oWD4.png)

Before that, make sure you have the flutter extension installed, otherwise you won't see the cli console setting. Hope this helps!