# stdin.readLineSync not accepting user's input after hitting enter

Tags: dart

I'm new in Dart. I'm trying to get basic user's input, but I have problems with that. Here is the code:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  stdout.writeln('Enter text: ');
  var input = stdin.readLineSync();
  stdout.writeln('Entered $input');
}
```

I'm working in VSCode in Windows, I've already changed in settings `dart.cliConsole` to `terminal` as many posts suggested, but still it only prints the first line "Enter text: " and when I type anything and hit enter - nothing happens. Moreover, when I build the app and trying to run it from normal cmd window outside of the VSCode - it doesn't print anything to console. Process Explorer shows that app is still running in the background as if it's waiting for user's input, but I can type any commands (like "dir" etc.) which works normally, and only after hitting Ctrl+C the app is killed. When I redirect output to the file I can see the first line "Enter text: " in that file. Using `print` instead of `stdout.writeln` doesn't change anything.

Comment: Can you try follow these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69911118/1953515

Comment: I've tried this before, it doesn't help.